# goroutines run post api in parallel with list of data

Tags: api, go

This is my first experience with go, I'm coming from a python background and I'm trying to run this post api(https://reqres.in/api/users) in parallel using goroutines with the different set of post data which is variable jsonStr in this code.

Any help much appreciated for running this api in paralle with the list of data

**My data**

data = [{"name": "bonny gaud", "movies": ["Terminator", "Transformer"],
        {"name": "Sarah palin", "movies": ["No country for old", "James Bond"] }

**My Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "bytes"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    url := "https://reqres.in/api/users"
    fmt.Println("URL:>", url)
    var jsonStr = []byte(`{"name": "paul rudd", "movies": ["I Love You Man", "Role Models"] }`)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
    req.Header.Set("X-Custom-Header", "myvalue")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println("response Status:", resp.Status)
    fmt.Println("response Headers:", resp.Header)
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))

    fmt.Print("Everything:", time.Since(start))
    fmt.Print(string(body))

}
```

Comment: In Go you execute stuff concurrently by using the `go` keyword, e.g. `go sendrequest(someinput)`.

Comment: For more details see: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements and https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1

Comment: Does it run in parallel with this and no need to use sync waitg

Comment: You can use a sync.WaitGroup if you need to synchronize multiple goroutines. If the goroutines don't care about each other and neither does the caller care about how they fare, then you do not need synchronization.

Comment: No, not in your code, there is no `go` statement there and so your code is completely synchronous, at least at the surface level. Go is not parallel by default, you need to use the `go` keyword, as already mentioned, to execute some function in a new goroutine, when you do that the parent goroutine does not wait for the child to finish. Have you taken the Go Tour? Did you look at those links? Did you try using the `go` statement?

Comment: Thanks i got it what are you tying to say, make sense to me on how parallelism works with go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use waitGroup or errGroup. Here is the example :

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    dataSets := []string{`{"name": "paul rudd", "movies": ["I Love You Man", "Role Models"] }`,
        `{"name": "paul rudd", "movies": ["I Love You Man", "Role Models"] }`}

    var eg errgroup.Group

    client := http.DefaultClient
    for _, jsonStr := range dataSets {
        eg.Go(func() error {
            return callClient(client, jsonStr)
        })
    }

    if err := eg.Wait(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Encountered error: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully finished.")
}

func callClient(client *http.Client, jsonStr string) error {
    start := time.Now()
    url := "https://reqres.in/api/users"
    fmt.Println("URL:>", url)

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(jsonStr)))
    req.Header.Set("X-Custom-Header", "myvalue")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("send request: %w", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println("response Status:", resp.Status)
    fmt.Println("response Headers:", resp.Header)

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("read body: %w", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))

    fmt.Print("Everything:", time.Since(start))
    fmt.Print(string(body))

    return nil
}
```

Comment: go get golang.org/x/sync